# Extracting just the year, month and day from this format

Tags: python, datetime

If I have a dict with date formatted as 'Thu May 01 04:19:08 +0000 2014' how do I go about extracting just the Year, Month and Day to a variable so that I can then search via date range. I need it in '%Y %M %D' '%H %M %S' using python.

Comment: check out https://strftime.org/

Comment: Basically, it seems best to parse the string to a `datetime` object first, then cast to string again, using only year/month/day or whatever you need

Comment: Thanks. If I parse datetime Thu May 01 04:19:08 +0000 2014 and it's looking for %m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S, how do I ignor the day of the week and change may into 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `datetime.datetime.strptime` to parse that string into a date object and then use `strftime` (str**f**time for **f**ormat, str**p**time for **p**arse) to extract it in your desired format.

```
import datetime

date = "Thu May 01 04:19:08 +0000 2014"
objectified = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
formatted = objectified.strftime("'%Y %M %D' '%H %M %S'")
```

```
>>> formatted
"'2014 19 05/01/14' '04 19 08'"
```

Placeholders are explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: Sensational!!! That got it sorted. Thanks so much for the help.